# Installing Elementary OS From DVD disc. Bios doesn't see usb stick as a bootable drive. Need to make an install disc, not an install stick

Tags: system-installation

Need to make an install disc, to install Elementary OS From DVD disc. Bios doesn't see usb stick as a bootable drive. Rufus only seems to make USB boot sticks.

Installing Elementary OS From DVD disc

Comment: What system are you using to make the image - Windows, Mac, or Linux?

Comment: Haven't made an image yet. I'm currently using Windows.

Answer (score 1):

For a Windows 10 system, you can use the built-in image burner. Put a writable DVD into the DVD burner. Right-click the elementary OS image and select **Burn disc image**.

Side note: I also had a PC with a BIOS that did not allow booting from a USB. I downloaded PLOP boot manager, burned it to disc, booted from it, and was then able to access the the USB drive to boot from it.
https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html